# Does python UDP receiver always receives only one message?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

About UDP receivers.
Consider the sample code below, do I have to consider that I might receive multiple UDP messaged in the `recfrom` method ?

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("", 99))
while 1:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    someFunction(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No to the question in the title.

Yes! to the question in the question. UDP packets often arrive twice (and out of order).

Wikipedia says:

> UDP uses a simple transmission model with a minimum of protocol
>   mechanism. It has no handshaking dialogues, and thus exposes any
>   unreliability of the underlying network protocol to the user's
>   program. As this is normally IP over unreliable media, there is no
>   guarantee of delivery, ordering or duplicate protection. UDP provides
>   checksums for data integrity, and port numbers for addressing
>   different functions at the source and destination of the datagram.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Sorry I'm little bit lost, you mean that the same message might receive twice?

Comment: Yes. You probably won't see this on your LAN, but it can happen easily when there are multiple paths etc.

Comment: Excellent, this will not be any problem for me even if I didn't know that, nice to have that knowledge in my pocket :)
Thanks!

Comment: Just to be more clear, let's say my messages is of size 200bytes, If I then make a call s.recvfrom(1024), might the return data include two messages? e.g. data="<msg1><msg2>"

Comment: @volt - no.  UDP datagrams are received individually, and in their entirety, (or not received at all, of course).